# Showing up bibliography in a report

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, report

I am trying to add a bobliography to my report the following way. But, it wouldn't happen. Checked a lot of tutorials and documentations, but I wasn't able to display it. Any brilliant idea, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %inclusion de figures
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node} %Graphiques
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newlength\mytemplength
\newcommand\parboxc[3]{%
    \settowidth{\mytemplength}{#3}%
    \parbox[#1][#2]{\mytemplength}{\centering #3}%
}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}

% for custom chapter
\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\newcommand*\ftsize[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{\numexpr 1.2*#1\relax pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand*\chapsubtitle[1]{{\LARGE #1}}
\newcommand\maketabular[1]{\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
  #1
\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}}{%
\vskip -120pt
\hspace{-10pt}
\begin{tabular}[b]{c !{\color{gray}\vline width1.5pt}}{\large\color{gray} \textls{CHAPITRE}}\\[2ex] \fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\thechapter\end{tabular}}{1em}{\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\maketabular}%[]

% to fix float's positions by being able to use the H property
\usepackage{float}

% for another level of subsections (subsubsubsection)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

% set the margins
\newgeometry{vmargin={30mm}, hmargin={20mm}}

% config of the header & footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% fix footnote's position to bottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{setspace}

% for tikz positioning
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.multipart, positioning}

% making the table of content clickable
\usepackage{hyperref}

% bibliography
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{3-appendices/references.bib}

% URLs
\usepackage{url}

% appendixes
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% for blank pages
\usepackage{afterpage}

% paragraph formatting
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}

\begin{document}

\include{0-configuration/configurations}
\include{1-opening/1.1-cover}
%\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\newpage
\include{1-opening/1.2-signings}

\newpage
\include{1-opening/1.3-acknowledgments}
\include{1-opening/1.4-abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\include{2-chapters/2.0-introduction}

\printbibliography[title = {References}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}References}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber You have to use an extra tool to generate something that LaTeX can handle.

Comment: You seem to use a template you found somewhere. It is bad. You cannot use `cite` package with `biblatex`. I suggest to use a [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports)

Comment: At the moment all we can say is that `cite` and `biblatex` are incompatible. Since you use the `biblatex` commands `\printbibliography` and `\addbibresource` you should drop `\usepackage{cite}`. You will also have to run Biber instead of BibTeX on your document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for concrete help with that and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for a bit of background. You also should not load packages multiple times (`hyperref`), and usually `hyperref` should be the last package loaded (`cleveref` is an exception and must be loaded after `hyperref`).

Comment: Any news here? Did removing `cite` and running LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX as suggested in the last comment help?

Comment: Any news here? At the moment we can't really tell what is going on here. We can only suggest the standard answers https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864.

Answer (score 1):

The code example is not really minimal (it loads unrelated packages) and not really working (it has many `\include`s whose contents we don't know).

---

One definite source of error in the preamble is the fact that the `cite` package and `biblatex` are both loaded. But the two packages are incompatible and only one of the two can be loaded. The remaining code suggests you use `biblatex`, so you should probably just remove `\usepackage{cite}`.

---

```
\printbibliography[title = {References}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}References}
```

should be replaced by

```
\printbibliography[title = {References}, heading=bibintoc]
```

---

You should also try to load packages only once. Load only the packages you need. `hyperref` should normally be loaded last (there are a few exceptions to this rule: `cleveref` for example must be loaded after `hyperref`).